# how to add file logging to c# graph api notification app (switch or extend Ilogger to log infos to a log-File)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, httpresponse, ilogger

i have started in the last few weeks working (or trying it) Simple MVC-App for notifications.

I can log informations to console  but how can I add easy an file logger for the notification function for http-requests?.
From the scratch  implementing with very much work I can realize it, but without any supporting functions for filelogging. I found the Ilogger to log in the Console. But is there an easy way to switch  Ilogger from logging to console logging to file?

```
  public class NotificationsController : ControllerBase
  {
    private readonly MyConfig config;
    private readonly ILogger<NotificationsController> _logger;

  public NotificationsController(MyConfig config, ILogger<NotificationsController> logger)
  {
      this.config = config;
            _logger = logger;
  }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get()
    {

               ...

            string Message = $"About page visited at {DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString()}";
            _logger.LogInformation(Message);

              ...
```

The example I modified is fromn here:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/5-exercise-change-notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/5-exercise-change-notifications)

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-changenotifications/tree/live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reaching out. AS.NET Core doesn't include a logging provider for writing logs to files, see documentation on [logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#built-in-logging-providers) To write logs to files, consider using a [third party logging provider.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#third-party-logging-providers)

Let me know whether this helps and if you have further questions.

Comment: Can you recommend some for file logging? On a quick look of this 3rd-party providers Ionly see nlog with file logging capability, but it seems either console or file logging but if it is easy use i would I could use so I hope: logging to console with ilogger and special contents to file. Are there side effects to expect or my case using booth loggers in http-handlers or are there better solutions?

Comment: I hope to get a more usefull hints or recommandations.
BUt my quesrion is anwsered, so i will accept the anwser.

Butz if some have recommandatuiohn for file -logging which is easy to handle owreks good in http request or other event handlers wchich use console logging and has no big overhead , feel free to answer or write a comment.